# What is the signifance of the Primary Group of a user?

Tags: users, group

Why must a user in POSIX-compliance have a Primary Group?  Why can't they just belong to groups?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The primary group is assigned to files created by that user...

Comment: So `touch` a file, and by default it will have the group of the Primary Group for that user.

Comment: … leading the questioner to come back with _Why do files need to have primary groups? Why can't they just have group ACL entries?_.  (-:

Comment: Yes (at least on Linux, BSDs are somewhat different, and a directory with setgid bit set behaves differently.) I'd say that's the most **apparent** effect of the primary group.